# Autofill / autocomplete on IE 11 and Safari

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, safari

We're having some issues with IE 11 and Safari users on our checkout page. We're selling ticket packs of 3 different types. The checkout form (besides credit card info, contact info) has ticket packs quantity fields like:

```
qtyA1
qtyA2
qtyA3
qtyA4
qtyB1
qtyB2
qtyB3
qtyC1
qtyC2
```

where user can specify one or more ticket pack he/she wants to order. User can enter a number of ticket packs with a keyboard or by clicking + and - buttons. Each of these fields are defined in HTML like

```
<div class="input-group">
<div class="input-group-addon input-group-addon-button" data-controls="qtyA1" data-add="-1">-</div>
<input type="text" min="0" max="9" maxlength="1" class="qty form-control input-group-button-input" autocomplete="false" name="qtyA1" id="qtyA1" data-ticket-type="A" data-price="10.00" data-ticket-qty="2" value="">
<div class="input-group-addon input-group-addon-button" data-controls="qtyA1" data-add="1">+</div>
```

(there are 9 fields like that, so I won't be pasting them all here).

The checkout is working fine for the last 2 years. But sometimes, in average once per 5k orders, user submits a form with all ticket packs options and then claims it's not what he/she intended to order. Our server receives a POST request with such a data:

```
qtyA1=1
qtyA2=1
qtyA3=1
qtyA4=1
qtyB1=1
qtyB2=1
qtyB3=1
qtyC1=1
qtyC2=1
```

Each ticket pack has a different ticket quantity and price. Ticket pack with higher price has more tickets in it. So it's more preferable to order 1 x qtyA2 than 2 x qtyA1. By ordering higher ticket pack, you can get more tickets for the same price or same amount of tickets for less amount. So it's pointless to order all options at once.

We have an autofill detection script, that is based on a field background change, but it seams like it's working only in Chrome, Firefox and probably in most but not all Safari browsers.

I'm not aware of any autofill features in IE (besides autocomplete).

Some of our findings on that issue:

- only customers using IE 11 or Safari browser have that issue
- 80% are 55+ years old and 60% are 65+
- 60% are returning customers and 2/3 of them had placed orders with same QTY issue
- 80% are paying with VISA
- almost every customer placed order with single submission, that is there were no errors with their credit cards in most cases.
- 11.8% of customers are using IE 9-11
- 31.7% are using Safari
- chances it happen to IE user are 0.038%
- chances it happen to Safari user are 0.014%

My thoughts on what might be causing the problem:

- autofill is not detected on IE and (probably) Safari.
- people might have some plugins installed with their browsers (some spying search toolbars that interact with a form when there is a credit card to be entered) - not likely, but you never know.
- elderly people are having difficulties with understanding ticket packages idea as only 20% of customers claim about their orders.
- as for elderly people they managed to place order pretty fast (3-5 minutes). Maybe they are using some Form data management tool/browser plugins? But I guess elderly people do not install things like that intentionally.
- JavaScript is disabled in customers' browser and it's preventing autofill detection.

[The test checkout is available here](http://checkout.salaciak.pl/)

The question is: **What is causing the form fields to be filled with ones on certain browsers and how to prevent it?**

Comment: can you make a fiddle

Comment: @SagarV I've altered the question, adding a link to the test checkout page, it's available here http://checkout.salaciak.pl/

Comment: `autocomplete` can either be `off` or `on`. You've defined it as `false`. Could that be an issue? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp

Comment: @31piy Right, I was playing with that value. Seams like `false` is respected by chrome (is not by IE). Changing it to `off` makes autocomplete not working for these fields for IE. But I'm pretty sure it's still not the solution. Something is autofilling the form with `1` for `qty` fields.

Comment: Tried to recreate the error, but sample checkout doesn't let me without entering valid personal info including credit card. Not willing to go that far, so could you perchance disable the part where the form is rejected due to invalid info?

Comment: @Uvar for testing purposes you can use fake CC details, like `5454 5454 5454 5454` and `111` as a CVV

Comment: Tried to recreate this error with the demo link, but I keep getting errors that the postal code format is invalid (it wants a zip+4) even when i'm using an actual zip code.

Comment: Although it is seriously obfuscated what Safari does with its autofill; it is known to seriously go crazy on labels: https://cdn.cloudfour.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Safari-Credit-Card-Autofill.gif
Perhaps if you change the label name from "Amount" to sth else, Safari will not trigger an autofill on amount = 1. <- it is a wild swing in the dark, but there should be a reason you only observe it with those few browsers.. (and I am wondering whether or not you should just use input type number instead of text)

Comment: @sorayadragon it's good it actually redirects back with error message on postal code. This way you can see what was posted to the server.

Comment: @Uvar I don't remeber now exactly, but there was a reason why we're not using number type of field (I should try that anyway). Thanks for your research.

Comment: This looks like a job posting from UpWork. Maybe you should hire someone to fix this.

Comment: @JeremiahBarrar yea, sort of ;-) I'm paying with reputation points for quality hints!

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a pretty nice bug to catch. If you find it, I'm pretty confident you can find some workarounds.

What I do in these situations is:

1) grab a month of BrowserStack subscription and start testing the hell out of it to reproduce the issue

I'm pretty sure you may have already checked but here are some other things I do:

a) Look once again for some flaw in the calculation algorightm, like unexpected output for unexpected input.

b) Make sure my calculations are not triggered by an unexpected event in js

c) I'm not reading field values too early:

For example when the user does the selection, try not to run you calculation directly and update the suggestions on the fly, but add a window timeout to do the calculation only after all field inputs are set:

`window.setTimeout(function() { handlevalues(); updateSuggestions();}, 500);`

I've seen this last case so often, as some browsers are providing invalid values on the spot due to their caching mechanisms and what not.

Comment: I'm not marking it as a proper answer yet as we need to test all these suggestions, but I'm awarding it as for research efforts. Thank you!